# Load Data Local Infile with Date

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert the current date and time to through a Load Data Local Inline statement. Would like to insert the current date and time through the command. Getting the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Date_Update=date('Y-m-d')' at line 3.

Here is my statement.

```
 $sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE contacts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
    (User_Category, Name, Logon_id, @Date_Update)
    SET ID=@ID, @Date_Update=date('Y-m-d');
    ";
```

Is setting the current date possible wih Load Data Local Infile?

Comment: I still get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Date_Update=NOW()' at line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the wrong assignation of the fields :

```
$sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE contacts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
    (User_Category, Name, @Logon_id, @Date_Update)     ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
    SET ID=@Logon_id, Date_Update=NOW();               ◄■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■■
    ";
```

Comment: @user3258571, please test this,  it compiles to me, and run it to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign to `@variable` in the `SET` clause. That should contain the table column you want to assign to, using `@variable` to get the column from the CSV file.

But if you want to insert the current date, you don't need to access a CSV column.

```
$sqlstatement="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$temp' INTO TABLE contacts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
    (User_Category, Name, Logon_id, @Date_Update)
    SET ID=@ID, Date_Update=TODAY();
    ";
```

BTW, `date('Y-m-d')` is a PHP function, not MySQL. The MySQL function for formatting dates and times is `DATE_FORMAT()`.

Comment: Barmar is there a possible error in your solution? Date_Update=Today(); , how is the field found in field set to import. Should it be (User_Category, Name, Logon_id, @Date_Update) and in set also @Date_Update. Either way doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Date_Update=NOW()' at line 3

Comment: Jose, I am using: (User_Category, Name, @ID, @Date_Update)
SET ID=@ID, @Date_Update=Today()

Comment: Barmar, I still get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@Date_Update=Today()' at line 3

Comment: @user3258571 The point is that the date doesn't come from the file you're importing. You just want to set the column to the current date unconditionally. You can only assign to table columns, not variables. `@variable` used as a placeholder for fields in the file.

Comment: If this isn't working, please show some sample lines from the file, and what you want the result in the table to be.